# Java read line until followstop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Actually, I am trying to read file which contain of multiple lines. for this I am using scanner.nextline()

However, I want to read the line until the followstop (dot separator) which usually followed by space or end of line char.

May any body help me in this case ?

Comment: what have you tryed? give us the code, and then it easyer to help you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search until a period, you can use a `Matcher` with a `Pattern`.

```
//Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\.]*\\.(\\s+)"); 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?\\.(\\s+)");  //Anything any amount of times, 
                                              //followed by a dot and then some whitespace.

Matcher matcher = p.matcher("firstword. secondword.\n");

while(matcher.find()){
    boolean space = matcher.group(1).charAt(0) == ' ';
    System.out.println(matcher.start() + matcher.group() + "and is space: " + (space ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"));
}
```

1. `.*?` - `.` will match anything. `*` matches 0 or more times. `?` is the [lazy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification) matcher. This matches any number of characters of any type, but it stops before the first period and whitespace (because of the lazy operator).
2. `\\.` - This matches a period. In Java, you have to double escape special characters in regexes.
3. `(\\s+)` - This means match whitespace (`\s`, which includes new lines) one or more times. It matches one or more whitespace characters. The parentheses "capture" this part of the regex so that every time you get a match on the regex you can just ask it what specific part was matched inside the parentheses. This lets you know if it is a space or a newline.

`matcher.group()` gets the string that was just matched.

I added in the question mark and commented out the other pattern because it sounded like you could have a period in the middle of some of your data. The question mark does "lazy" matching. By default, matching is greedy and will take the longest matching string. So if there are multiple places in the string with a period followed by a whitespace, it will return all of that as one match. The laziness forces it to stop matching any character (.*) once it reaches the first period and space.

Comment: thank you for your reply.... actually I dont understand this pattern and what if I want to read to the dot followed by (space or newline char)

Comment: Ok. I'll break it down more in there. I added \s for the whitespace.

Comment: thank you I will try and I will see what happen .... but how to deal with the new line char (\n) and white space together

Comment: The new line character *is* whitespace. You could just check to see which one is the last character of your string, or you could match a group at the end. I'll add that to it as soon as I figure out why the whitespace part of the regex is not working.

Comment: thank you alot .... I tried your code and it success in your example .... 
but when I have used this in my program as following 

scanner = new Scanner(file);scanner.useDelimiter(".*?\\.(\\s+)");

Comment: thank you alot .... I tried your code and it success in your example .... but when I have used this in my program as following scanner = new Scanner(file);
scanner.useDelimiter(".*?\\.(\\s+)");

Comment: If you can, use the matcher instead of the scanner. I can't test the scanner right now, but it wasn't working when I was trying it. No, no, no... don't use `useDelimiter`. If you have to use `Scanner`, try `next(Pattern pattern)`. A delimiter separates your "words" (tokens to put it in formal terms). If you had "see|spot|run" you could set your delimiter to "|" and it would return "see" and then "spot" and then "run". Using my regex string as a delimiter will **not** give you expected results. Instead the regex actually matches the **words** (tokens), not the characters between them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the read() method and read char by char. If you''re matching the . this is your newline character.

Other solution might be to set the newline character and then use readline(). I did not tried this howeever

or read file in once ans use string.split method

Answer (score 0):

```
FileReader fin = new FileReader("yourfile.txt");
Scanner src = new Scanner(fin);
// Set delimiters to full stop

src.useDelimiter(".");


while (src.hasNext()) {
  // do what you want here
  }
```

Comment: I tried to use this method but if I have (.) followed by any thing else for example 23.5 it will consider that the dot is a line separator.

Comment: I will do my best in order to run what you have sent to me and I will see what will happen .... thank you alot

Comment: So why don't you try adding a space after the "." so it becomes ". " like this: src.useDelimeter(". ");

Comment: You know this has 700 extra close braces and an else without if, right? Not trying to be mean, but it does need some formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.contains(". ") || line.trim().endsWith("."))
            {
                int length = line.indexOf(". "); // get the index when the line contains dot and space in the middle
                stringBuilder.append(line.trim().endsWith(".") ? line
                        : line.substring(0, length).replace(". ", "." + System.getProperty("line.separator"))); // when the line contains dot at the end or the line may contain the dot with space
                System.out.println("stringBuilder : " + stringBuilder.toString());
                stringBuilder.delete(0, stringBuilder.toString().length());
                if (length != 0)
                {
                    stringBuilder.append(line.substring(length+2, line.length()));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                stringBuilder.append(line.replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"), " "));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("stringBuilder : "+stringBuilder.toString()); // when the last line not end with dot or not contain dot and space
```