# how scanner read line dot separator

Tags: java

I tried to to read the file lines line by line until dot separator. However as some body told me that I can use some patterns. I used the following and it seems like it work but I got the following problem:

```
scanner = new Scanner(file);
scanner.useDelimiter(".*?\\.(\\s+)");
```

In the following example :

> COMMACK, N.Y., Feb 26 - Computer Terminal Systems Inc said it has
>   completed the sale of 200,000 shares of its common stock, and warrants
>   to acquire an additional one mln shares, to  of Lugano,
>   Switzerland for 50,000 dlrs.

But the output is :

> COMMACK, N.Y., Feb 26 - Computer Terminal Systems Inc said it has
>   completed the sale of 200,000 shares of its common stock, and warrants
>   to acquire an additional one mln shares, to

It seems like it work correctly but some time it doesn't complete until then end . so what is the problem?

Comment: You already asked this question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java read line until followstop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397840/java-read-line-until-followstop)

Comment: @newuser-when you know its a duplicate, and you already provided an answer there, why duplicate your own answer?! Instead mark this post as duplicate and share your answer link here in the comments section.

Comment: @R.J ya i know but here the questionare will give the exact input and output my answer contains some changes from the previous one. So only i posted here again

Comment: @newuser - That's the whole point. Edit that answer. Mark this as a duplicate and provide the link of your answer present there. The link will re-direct to your answer always, no matter, how much you edit or change.

Comment: see the updated answer that may help you

Answer (score 0):

I tried this [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397840/java-read-line-until-followstop/19398146#19398146)

use trim while the line that may be end with the dot.